# FinalizationRegistry callback not called

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand FinalizationRegistry in JavaScript.
As per the MDN docs the FinalizationRegistry callback function will be called as soon as the object it is weakly referencing is lost. I tried with a simple example but doesn't seem to work.

```
const obj = {a:'GC'}
registry = new FinalizationRegistry(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
registry.register(obj, "Garbage collected");
delete obj; //deletes obj from the global context, but FinalizationRegistry registry callback not called
```

Can someone please give a simple working example?

Comment: There's a section in the "notes" part of the MDN docs. --- _"A conforming JavaScript implementation, even one that does garbage collection, **is not required to call cleanup callbacks**. When and whether it does so is entirely down to the implementation of the JavaScript engine. When a registered object is reclaimed, any cleanup callbacks for it may be called then, or some time later, **or not at all**."_

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks, I read that, I am trying to understand if there is any way we can implement FinalizationRegistry callback in any use-case with absolute certainty?

Comment: You cannot `delete` a `const`.

Comment: @Boris I'm not sure you can, no

Comment: i have a good answer to this question, but it is closed for some unknown reason

Comment: @TridentD'Gao It is closed for the reason that the problem with the code is already explained in https://stackoverflow.com/q/742623/1048572, and the "*simple working example*"s are given in the other duplicates. What would you add to that?

Comment: If you want to post such an example, you can also write an answer for https://stackoverflow.com/q/66723378/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/q/20266610/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/6077374/1048572

Comment: it's asking for a simple working example and i have it

i am not saying it's not a duplicate, however for what it's worth there is an exact answer to this exact question, and i don't understand the resistance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66723378/ is also asking for a "*real simple example*", why not post it there? I don't think it's useful to mix that with an explanation why `delete` does not work on variables. Those should be two separate questions, answered separately.

Comment: True, that question is also not perfect since it mixes weak references and finalisers, you may actually want to post a complete new question to act as a canonical about `FinalizationRegistry`. But I still think Robin's question "*why is this `FinalizationRegistry` code not working*" is not very useful and should not be reopened, since it actually isn't about the `FinalizationRegistry` at all.

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77588120/how-can-i-see-that-finalizationregistry-indeed-invokes-the-given-callback-when-a