# How can I see that FinalizationRegistry indeed invokes the given callback when an object gets consumed by the garbage collector?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

In the latest Chrome browser `119.0.6045.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)` in December, 2023, on Windows 10, I run the following snippet in the **Chrome DEV console**, and I expect to see the `Garbage collected` message in the output of the said console, but I don't, what am I doing wrong?

```js
const obj = {};
const registry = new FinalizationRegistry(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
registry.register(obj, 'Garbage collected');
```

**PS:** this question and answer was originally thought to be a part of

- [FinalizationRegistry callback not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70230353/finalizationregistry-callback-not-called)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no way to tell when the garbage collector kicks in. So you can sit and wait and it will never happen, because of specifics of the implementation and strategies the garbage collector follows. It's up to the team who developed it and there is nothing said in the specs as to what to expect.

Secondly, running the code from the DEV console of the browser makes all given objects linger in the memory (with hard links to it) that prevents the garbage collector from snatching them, why? Because that's what the console is for: for you to check the objects at any time you want, that's why they can't be disposed. So what does it mean? It means that if you declare `const obj = {}` in the console there will be a hard link to it by the console itself that will prevent the `obj` from being collected. See how it is fixed down below.

Thirdly, the team who developed the browser has intentionally removed any control of the GC from the API of the browser, because it's better this way, so typically you cannot make it go faster to see the expected results, but there is a hack.

So what can you do to see that `FinalizationRegistry` works?

This is what worked for me:

**STEP 1:**

- run `cmd.exe` and from it start chrome with `--js-flags="--expose-gc"`

```
chrome.exe --js-flags="--expose-gc"
```

*WHY?* because by default there is no access to the garbage collector API in Chrome, you cannot manually invoke it from the code or the console (in fact you can from the Memory tab clicking on the trash can button), but with this option you can do it in the code. So with this option you can see that `gc` function is now available.

**STEP 2:**

- in the browser, open the DEV console (by pushing F12) and paste there:

```js
const registry = new FinalizationRegistry(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
(function() {
   registry.register({}, "Garbage collected");
})();
```

*WHY IIFE?* Because the object that we register needs to be **short lived**, and for that it needs to created inside the scope of a *Immediately Invoked Function Expression* (IIFE), so that it's a subject for garbage collector, since there are not refs to it anywhere in the code

**STEP 3:**

- to the same console paste:

```js
gc();
```

*WHY?* because we don't have much time to sit and wait, we want the GC to kick in right now, without doing it your might not ever see the expected result

- observe:

[image]

Comment: "*the team who developed the browser has intentionally removed any control of the GC from the API of the browser*" - this is incorrect. In the "memory" tab of the devtools, there's actually a button for it. This is much easier than starting the whole browser with `--js-flags="--expose-gc"`

Comment: Why did you change `const registry` to `window.registry`? Also the IIFE is unnecessary. What matters is only that you don't declare `const obj` in the console scope.

Comment: Hey thanks, cool to see an answer after 2 years 